# view loading "by hand" in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using the zend framework and trying to create and render a view from inside a controller. Normally this process is handled by the framework but I thought I could do it myself too as this part of the [documentation states](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.controllers.html).

Unfortunately there is something wrong as the framework is still trying to load the default view as  well. Here's my controller

```
<?php

class ViewController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    private $viewsFolder = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->viewsFolder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../views/custom/';
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        // using a custom view (initialization and rendering executed by hand)
        $view = new Zend_View();

        $view->setScriptPath($this->viewsFolder);

        $view->assign(array(
            "dev_name" => "Fabs",
            "framework" => "Zend frmwrk"
        ));

        echo $view->render('customView.phtml');
    }
}
```

and here is the error I get

```
Message: script 'view/index.phtml' not found in path (/home/ftestolin/stuff/rubrica/application/views/scripts/)
```

It looks like the normal view rendering cannot be suppressed. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: 18 questions and 1 accepted answer - sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Probably better to disable the `ViewRenderer` rather than remove it. In controller:

`$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);`

Remember that the `ViewRenderer` is where `Zend_Form` instances pull their default view for their own rendering. Removing the `ViewRenderer` means that it has to be re-instantiated later when the form needs to render. But when it does so, it recreates a *brand new* `Zend_View` instance. Any settings you have applied to your view - say, at bootstrap, setting doctype, etc - will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

ok I will answer myself :)

one has to prevent the normal behaviour which is handled by Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer

you can do it like that in the controller and then do your View instantiation business.

```
$this->_helper->removeHelper('viewRenderer'); // stop the default views rendering process
```

cheers